# Track from where link is clicked node.js

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

I'm trying to **track** from **where** my **links are clicked**.

Exemple I place a link to my website on `facebook`, `instagram`, `linkedin`.

I would like to know where my link is clicked most of the time. 
bit.ly does it and I don't know how.

One of my ideas was to identify links like

- `www.exemple.com/facebook_url`
- `www.exemple.com/instagram_url`

but if I can avoid this it would be perfect.

Any idea ? :)

Comment: Is this for anylitics?

Comment: You might want to read about UTM codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how !

`req.headers.referer;`

give me the url used to redirect my user :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to set up a web server with redirects and analytics already built in. You could also build your own analytics using a redirecting html + js

If you have access to a webserver, you could use PHP to do a conditional redirect.

Comment: I'm trying to do this. I'm in a startup that need to have their own redirect system. I try to redirect with no views with `res.redirect()` but i need to know from where does the link got clicked to get more datas.

Comment: Do you have a webserver? @JérémyMisiti

Comment: If you have one, you can use PHP to make conditional redirects.

Comment: Yes i have a node.js webserver. I just wan't to know from where my user clicked on my link.

Comment: You will have to make a difference on each link. The only exception for this is if it is on your own pages. @JérémyMisiti